# Does multiple virtual inheritance involve late binding like inheritance of virtual functions?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

Unlike inheriting virtual functions, resolving virtual inheritance seems cut and dry but maybe I'm just not creative (devious?) enough.

Is virtual inheritance at all related to inheritance of virtual functions? Specifically, will virtual inheritance ever incur late binding? I can't see any reason why. I'm only suspicious because of the keyword overload.

I realize the standard doesn't specify implementation of virtual inheritance. I'm interested in whatever most non-hypothetical machines do, however imperfect.

Comment: Well, it's at least not obvious why it isn't cut and dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual inheritance is not without runtime costs, however the reason for this cost is not an increase in flexibility, but the resolving of an ambiguity.

Take for example a multiple inheritance hierarchy where class `C` inherits class `A` twice through different base classes. The call to a non-static method `A::foo` on an object of type `C` is now ambiguous (whether that call is virtual or not). The problem is the implicit `this` pointer passed to the member function. Usually, the position of each subclass in memory is determined uniquely by the inheritance hierarchy, but in this case, since `A` is included twice in `C`, the compiler must decide how to adjust the `this` pointer for the member function call - which it cannot do on its own, so it will ask you to decide.

This decision is further complicated since we can not only call `A::foo` through `C`, but also through `C`'s base classes. This creates a dilemma: Depending on which base class we use to make the call, the compiler will adjust the `this` pointer differently, redirecting us to different locations for `A` in memory, depending on what pointer type we use for the call. We in fact have two distinct instances of `A` in memory for every single instance of `C`.

```
class A {
public:
    void foo();
    [...]
};
class B1 : public A {};
class B2 : public A {};
class C : public B1, public B2 {};

C c;
B1* b1 = &c;
B2* b2 = &c;

//assume foo() changes some internal state of A
b1->foo();
//the state change of the previous line is not visible
//to the next call - they operate on distinct instances of A
b2->foo();
```

`virtual` inheritance introduces an additional layer of indirection to resolve this ambiguity. Instead of determining the position of `A` relative to its subclasses at compile time, a runtime lookup is performed. This allows the compiler to pass the same memory location calls `A::foo`, no matter through which derived class the call was made. For each instance of `C`, we now only have a single instance of `A` in memory.

```
class B1 : virtual public A {};
class B2 : virtual public A {};
[...]

C c;
B1* b1 = &c;
B2* b2 = &c;

//both calls will now operate on the same instance of A
//state changes performed by the one will be observed by the other
b1->foo();
b2->foo();
```

Comment: "_the reason for this cost is not an increase in flexibility_" 1) virtual provides increase in flexibility 2) with an indirection

Comment: @curiousguy Can you give an actual example where virtual inheritance provides an increase in flexibility other than resolving the aforementioned ambiguity in a multi-inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: For example, the call of the base class constructor can be (actually, must be) "overidden" in the most derived constructor.

Comment: @curiousguy Constructor calls are always resolved at compile time. Virtual inheritance has no effect here. This includes calls from the derived class constructor to a base class constructor. The derived class already knows all of its concrete bases, so there is no need for an indirection.

Comment: Overriding is also resolved at compile time. Virtual inheritance implies that the constructor is called by the most derived class.

Answer (score 5):

Just as virtual functions involve late binding *of those member functions*, I suppose you could say that virtual inheritance involves late binding *of inherited data members*. The memory layout of each subclass is potentially quite different, so an expression like `baseClassInstance->dataMember` cannot be resolved without run-time type information. Both uses of `virtual` therefore require the use of "vtables" for class-specific lookup.

See ["Memory Layout for Multiple and Virtual Inheritance", by Edsko de Vries](http://web.archive.org/web/20160413064252/http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html), for an explanation of how the GNU Compiler Cluster (gcc) implements virtual inheritance, including object layout, consequences, etc. As far as I'm aware, other compilers are similar in the key points.

Comment: Shouldn't we call it late binding of _ancestor class_?

Comment: @bipll: I don't see why, or even what that would mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Don't inherited data members constitute the ancestor class?

Comment: @bipll: If you want to view "class" as meaning simply "collection of data members", then -- sure, "of the ancestor class" would be equivalent to "of inherited data members". But I'm not sure why you consider that to be better/clearer. \*shrug\*